# How to override lazy import() resolution in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, cdn

I have an odd request. I'm trying to implement a plugin for webpack that can dynamically resolve the CDN location of a chunk. I'm aware of the publicPath options and their behavior, however, in my case this is not possible. Because with our CDN, we don't get a URL back that includes the relative path of the file, instead it returns a magic ID we use to create a URL, regardless of the file location/name.

For example:

```
/static/js/chunk.1.js -> https://cdn.example/asset/1234
main.js -> https://cdn.example/asset/1122
```

I can create a chunk name/location map, and I'm ok with the additional bundle size overhead of including this map in my final output for runtime resolution. What I'm having difficulty finding is ideally overriding the default webpack import() behavior.

Like ideally, the same syntax:

```js
const chunkResult = await import('/lazy-loaded');
```

Would essentially translate to something like:

```
const chunkResult = await load('https://cdn.example/assets/1234');
```

Any suggestions on how this might be accomplished or a "you can't do that, submit a feature request" would be great.

Comment: A different approach to import scripts from CDN in runtime will be to override the [webpack_chunk_load](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_chunk_load__-webpack-specific) function with itself and add a prefix of https:/cdn.example/ so all your assets will be served from the CDN, will this suffice?

Comment: That sounds promising I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can control the public path of webpack dynamically by [`__webpack_public_path__`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__webpack_public_path__-webpack-specific).

For example many solutions are out there which provide fallbacks from cdn to your service by changing the `__webpack_public_path__` dynamiclly when the script tag for the cdn returns an error.

Write a simple:

`__webpack_public_path__ = window.cdnEndpoint`

and webpack will compile it to the publicPath.

Comment: But this only controls the base path "https://cdnjs.com/my-package/", I need to control the entire url with a mapping from chunk path to file id resolving